# Pickling Data of Custom Format

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I need to pickle data that is of the form: a table of multiple rows having

a list of tuples, a list

e.g. [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] is associated with [1,2,3]

I can't find a way to pickle the data and load it so that I get:

```
import cPickle
f = open("data.pkl", 'rb')
X,Y = cPickle.load(f)
```

so that X has only the first column of the data and Y has the second column.

I was thinking to store the first column and second column separately, but then how could I load such data in one statement?

```
a = []
a.append( [(1,2),(2,3)] )
```

and similarly for the second column.

```
b = []
b.append([1,2])
```

Then how to pickle it and unpickle it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried `Bunch` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Bunch(dict):
    """Container object for datasets
    Dictionary-like object that exposes its keys as attributes.
    >>> b = Bunch(a=1, b=2)
    >>> b['b']
    2
    >>> b.b
    2
    >>> b.a = 3
    >>> b['a']
    3
    >>> b.c = 6
    >>> b['c']
    6
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(kwargs)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

import cPickle as pickle

dataset = Bunch.Bunch(data=X, target=Y,
                         target_names=target_names_input,
                        DESCR=fdescr,feature_names=labels_names)

def save_object(obj, filename):
with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

save_object(dataset,'data.pkl')

with open('data.pkl', "rb") as f:
data = pickle.load(f)
X = data.data
Y = data.target
```

I assumed you had some form of feature data in the rows of your table `X` and that your column `Y` is the target vector.

Comment: thanks, yes X is feature data and y is target vector. I didn't get how you are first saving and then pickling here.

Comment: @Rafael if this answer solved your problem you can express your thanks by marking it as accepted :)

Comment: sure, i will mark it as accepted. here, first i need to save x and y in a file (assume x and y both are lists). then in a pickle file. My confusion is how is the format preserved across the file. Here, i don't see how data is stored in a file.

Comment: hi, i can't get it working on say sample data: X = [(1,2), (2,3)]
Y = [1,2] .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import cPickle

FILENAME = 'foo.pkl'

X = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
Y = [1,2,3]

with open(FILENAME, 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump((X, Y), f)

with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as f:
    x, y = cPickle.load(f)

print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: do you mean with open('data2.pkl', "rb") as f:
   pickle.dump((X, Y), f) . Please give a simple example of dumping and loading X Y that i can run. thanks a lot.